# multiple rows with a single UL

Tags: html

I have following:

```
<ul>
<li>copy</li>
<li>copy</li>
<li>copy</li>
<li>copy</li>
<li>copy</li>
<li>copy</li>
<li>copy</li>
<li>copy</li>
... 50 rows...
<ul>
```

I have a very long UL list, is there a sexy way I can split it to be 2 or 3 rows using CSS?? I cannot make multiple `<ul>`'s unfortunately.. :(

Thankful for any type of help.

Comment: This article helped me to have list elements wrap inside its container: http://actionscript-flash-guru.com/blog/46-multiple-row-ul-multi-line-list-css-html

Answer (score 1):

If you styled the `<li>` elements with "float: left" and maybe a fixed width, they'd line up sort-of like a table. Is that what you mean?

Might also want to play with margin & padding, and set "list-style: none" because bullets or whatever would look weird.

*edit* — the CSS might look something like:

```
ul.whatever li {
  float: left; margin-left: 10px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Depends on the contents etc. whether this would look better or worse of course.

Comment: I did try that, but didnt work the way I wanted to :(
do you have a css snippet I can try? the class of the UL is 'list-33'

Comment: @vick - What happened? Why wasn't it what you wanted?